# Javascript export/import doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I just want to import a custom js module on another js file.

on html head:

```
<script  src="Dictionary.js" type="module"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Templates.js" ></script>
```

On Module:

```
 var Dictionary=function() {...}
 export {Dictionary};
```

On js File:

```
import {Dictionary} from './Dictionary';
```

I get these errors

On Chrome:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

On Firefox

> SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a
>   module

The two files are in the same folder.

Comment: try changing `type="text/javascript"` to `type="module"` on your second `<script>` tag

Comment: The file disappeared from the sources files when I did that.

Comment: I tried again adding the `.js` again and it actually worked!! Thank you very much.

Comment: How did you fixed it ?

Answer (score 1):

When importing don't add the ".js"

```
import {Dictionary} from 'Dictionary';
```

See the doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)

Comment: Didn't solve the problem still getting the same errors. I've corrected it though.